# Sublime text editor: Unable to process using

Tags: python, sublimetext3

In sublime I tried using terminus for my builds so I could use the input function.

The build code is as follows:

python_terminus.sublime-build

```
{
    "target": "terminus_exec",
    "cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",
    "cmd": [
        "py", "-u", "$file"
    ],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
}
```

After building a basic python program asking for an input I get the following error.

*Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -OO -u "C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Documenten\name.py"': The system cannot find the file specified.*

I cant get rid of this error knowing that the build file works on another PC.

I installed python 3.11 but since I wanted to work on the same version as on my other platforms I deleted it and installed Python 3.8.

Anybody an idea what to do?
I tried nummerous things, reinstalling, removing python 3.11 (which I can not do), changing my environment variables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you open a command prompt and enter `py -u C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Documenten\name.py` do you get the same error?

Comment: Do you mean first go to the file in the directory in command prompt being `C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Documenten\name.py and after that type py -u` ?
If I type in `C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Documenten py -u` I do get the same error

Comment: If you can `cd` into the folder the file is in, run `py -u C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Documenten\name.py` and it works, but from Terminus it does not, then the issue is somewhere with Terminus or your Sublime setup; if it doesn't work in the console either, it's an issue with Python itself and is unrelated to Sublime. It would also be interesting to know if it still fails for files that aren't in the `OneDrive` folder

Comment: Okay thanks for helping me narrowing this down. What I got so far:
If I go into the folder and do `py -u ` I get the following error.
`Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\joren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe  -u': The system cannot find the file specified.`
I put this file just into my harddrive and got the same error as before, just the path to the second file changed to the current filepath of the new python file. So I think it is Python related.

Comment: Since the problem was with python, I succeeded in deleting all type of python files and I freshly installed python 3.11.4.
If I go now into the command prompt and type `C:\Users\Owner> py -m install` I get the following error:
`C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: No module named install`

Comment: If I now do the same thing you suggested first go into the folder using command prompt and type in `py -u` I get the following: `Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

So if I understand right now python works?
But I get the same error as I specified in my previous answer, when building the project

Comment: So, that would indicate that Python is probably working as expected; so the next thing would be to be in that folder, and run the `py -u` command and give it the name of the file to process; the issue could be that OneDrive is causing you problems. You could also test that by storing your Python file in a location that's not part of OneDrive and seeing if the problem persists or not.

Comment: I tried storing the same file in a different location on my C drive. After that I ran the `py -u` command and this seems to work with python version 3.11.4 . I tried this with OneDrive and this works aswell. If I now run my code in sublime. which is just asking for an input and printing the given input, I get the same error as stated in the initial question.

Comment: @OdatNurd So far I know that python does work and that I installed terminus as a package. I know that the build file works, since I tested it on another PC. So I am kindoff hardstuck on this one .. Do you still have any ideas? Thanks